# How to create a dynamic 2d array in python

Tags: python, arrays

So my question has been asked but its a bit different so I dont know how to apply this.

I have 2 variables I want to use in an array since I have to do an operation with them .  Variable1 goes from 0 to 7 while Variable2 can and will go from 0 to 18000 or in some cases bigger... of course variable2  is just an int , and is the variable I care. so lets say I have Variable1 = 5, Variable2 = 1553 and then I get another Variable 1 = 5 and Variable2= 1200  I want to be able go and find the lowest value fo Array[5][Variable2] .  which means that it would return me the value 1200.

In other words, Variable1 will always be a value between 0 and 7, which I want to use it to index the other array containing all values from variable2, data is polled serially inside a for loop, so I get data for both variables constantly.

An example of the data would be :

```
sensor.variable1=2, sensor.variable2 = 1000
sensor.variable1=3, sensor.variable2 = 900
sensor.variable1=1, sensor.variable2 = 880
sensor.variable1=2, sensor.variable2 = 900
sensor.variable1=1, sensor.variable2 = 880
```

So the question is how would I deal with a situation like this where I receive data constantly and want to fill a 2d dimension array with a number of data until a certain point . using variable1 to be the index to allow me to save each value of variable2.  An example I think would be using the 3 datapoints above, and considering 0 the first value of the array:

```
ArrayOfData[1][1]= 880
```

I would of course receive a constant stream of data and this is inside a loop, my goal is to at least have several datapoints per variable1, so I do have a set limit I could hardcode in the loop maybe after 1000 datapoints, this of course could mean 1000 datapoints where variable1 = 1 , however it could also be a situation where datapoints have different variable 1 and its not in order so using a loop to fill the array based on variable1 is not going to be possible.

Comment: Sorry, I can't understand what you mean at all. Do `Variable1` and `Variable2` represent the *size* of the array you want? or are they just two values that you want to put into a single variable? When you say "I do not know the number of variables I will have in variable 2", I don't understand that at all. What do you mean when you say that there is more than one variable in your variable? And when you say that "the data is received serially" - what data, and what receipt? It would help if you *showed some relevant code*.

Comment: all python lists are dynamically allocated, which means to make a 2d array you can just do ```array = [[]]``` if you want it some nxm array, then you can do ```array = [[0]*m for _ in range(n)]```

Comment: variable1 would define the size of one dimension of the array, while variable2 I just want the values. Variable1 will always be between 0 and 7 , while variable2 can be any value and will constantly change but I want to save most of them until a certain point. and my main issue is since I am polling a sensor I am getting data constantly and I am trying to quickly build either 8 arrays, or 1 2d array with all the values I need until a certain point. since the loop will never end and is not supposed to end I just want to build the array fast so I can use it for more processing.